# Discrete Probability Problem?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

> You are playing a game, in which at every stage you can either win a dollar or lose one, with probabilities $p$ and $1-p$, respectively. The game is going until you don't have any money. You start with $N_0= \$1$ in the beginning. What is the probability that after the stage $n$ you have again $N_n=\$1$ in your bank?

So I have been trying to solve this for some time. I have no idea on how to get started. From what I understand, perhaps the probability that I looking for is that when the number of success equal to number of failures. That's only way(that I can think of) that you can end up with the 1 dollar you started with ? I also feel like this is a Bernoulli trial problem but I just cant seem to apply anything to this. Any solutions/explanations would be highly appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is odd the probability is of course zero.  If $n$ is even, the probability is $C_{n/2}p^{n/2}(1-p)^{n/2}$ where $\displaystyle C_k = \frac{1}{k+1}\binom{2k}{k}$ is the $k$-th Catalan number.

How can we see this?  Consider that to get back to $\$1$, we need to have a sequence of $n/2$ wins and $n/2$ losses, where at no point do we have more losses than wins.  There are exactly $C_{n/2}$ such sequences.  Each of these sequences of wins and losses has equal probability $p^{n/2}(1-p)^{n/2}$, giving the probability of one of these sequences occurring as $$\frac{1}{(n/2)+1}\binom{n}{n/2}p^{n/2}(1-p)^{n/2}.$$